# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\{x\ |\ f(a)\le f(x)<f (a)+1/n\})=0$ implies continuity a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis

$ x \in \mathbb{R} $ , $ f: \mathbb{R}  \to  \mathbb{R} $, $ f $ is measurable ,$\mu$ is Lebesgue outer measure.

$ A_{n, a}=\{x\ |\ f(a)\le f(x)<f (a)+\frac {1}{n}\}$ for any $ a  \in 
\mathbb{R}  $

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_{n,a})=0$ for all $ a$ implies continuity of $ f(x)$ a.e.?

@GEdgar reduced the problem to if there is a measurable $ f$ such that $$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu (A_{n,a}) = \mu\left\{x\ |\ f(a) = f(x)\right\} =0
$$ holds for all  $ a $ and discontinuous ae ?

Comment: Your definition $ A_n=\{x\ |\ f(a)\le f(x)<f (a)+\frac {1}{n}\}$ doesn't really make much sense, because there's no connection specified between $x$ and $a$.

Comment: No, since even in case where you had $A_n=\{a\}$ (which would be a problem for continuity) and you will still have then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu$$(A_n)=0$.... So this criteria seems totally unrelated to continuity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a$.  The set $A_{n,a}$ decreases as $n$ increases, and
$$
\bigcap_n A_{n,a} = \left\{x\ |\ f(a) = f(x)\right\}
$$
so
$$
\lim_n \mu (A_{n,a}) = \mu\left\{x\ |\ f(a) = f(x)\right\}
$$
Thus, your condition means: $f$ takes each value on a set of measure zero, possibly empty.

For example, as Netchaief noted, this holds if $f$ is injective ($f$ takes each value on a set with at most one element).

That does not imply $f$ is continuous a.e.

How about this example: $f(x) = x$ for $x$ rational, and $f(x) = -x$ for $x$ irrational.  It is injective, but continuous only at the point $0$.

**added**
For the new definition of "discontinuous a.e." use this example.  Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set).  So both $A$ and its complement have inner measure zero.  Then our example is $f(x) = x$ for $x \in A$ and $f(x) =-x$ for $x \notin A$.

Comment: You are saying there exists a measurable function $ f$ such that $$
\lim_n \mu (A_{n,a}) = \mu\left\{x\ |\ f(a) = f(x)\right\}
$$ holds for all  $ a $  and discontinuous ae?

Comment: In fact $$\lim_n \mu (A_{n,a}) = \mu\left\{x\ |\ f(a) = f(x)\right\}$$ holds for all functions.  The claim is that there exists a function such that $$\mu\left\{x\ |\ f(a) = f(x)\right\}= 0$$ and is discontinuous a.e.

Comment: I agree that this may have nothing to with measure +1)

Comment: @GEdgar : you summed up well this property. I thought at first at a counterexample of the kind of you gave, but the clame was discontinuous a.e and this one is equal a.e to the function $x\mapsto -x$, so it is continuous a.e.